Alternative to random intercept cross-lagged panel model
I'm looking for some inspiration as how to best model a given phenomenon, thought I'd ask around here.
This is a study where we will be collecting 5 repeated measures (say blood pressure, BP) over the course of disease progression. At those 5 times, we will also collect a specific blood marker (BM). We believe this blood marker causes changes in blood pressure. There a few possibilities (1. high and consistent average levels of BM causes BP changes over time; 2. BM, at a time prior to BP, will explain the future changes in BP; 3. BM increases linearly over time, leading to increased changes in BP.  The exact time at which the blood pressure changes occur is not known (we know it happens somewhere between time 0 and time 5, but no idea if it happens on time 2, 3 or 4).
I thought of using a Random Intercept Cross-Lagged Panel Model (RI-CPLM), but I’m looking for a simpler approach. For instance, I’m not interested in BP -> BM changes, so I thought I don’t need the ‘crossed’ part of CLPM. The other limitation is that while the effects we observe are typically large, we have a very limited sample size (50-100 subjects) and so a RI-CPLM is not powered enough based on monte-carlo simulations.
Ideally, In the end I'd also like to assess moderation (e.g. if the association between BM and BP larger when disease severity is also larger)
Any suggestions, recommended readings, etc?
Your help is much appreciated

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If disease severity is a stable variable (=its value remains the same for each participant throughout the study), wouldn't a multilevel model with random (participant-specific) slope of BM and a cross-level interaction between severity and BM work?
